# wrapper | OpenSCManager failed - Access is denied. (0x5)

Tags: archiva

I am trying to install Archiva on windows 8.1 pro (64 bit) and I am continuously getting the same error as below

wrapper  | OpenSCManager failed - Access is denied. (0x5).

I logged in as administrator only. But still I am getting the same error. Most of the answers for the same problem I am seeing it for VISTA and 7 etc.. But not for Windows8.1 Pro (64 bit)

Answer (score 9):

You need to run that command as an administrator.

- Right-click on the command prompt entry in the start menu / task bar
- Select "Run as Administrator"
- Navigate to the Archiva installation directory

Then run:

```
bin\archiva install
net start archiva
```

Comment: I found out the command how to run as administrator in Windows 8.1 Pro. Right click on Windows key where we will find out the command to run as administrator. Thanks for all your answers

Answer (score 1):

Type cmd as shown below:

[image]

Run as administrator as shown below:

[image]

Comment: This procedure applies to installing any program, just run as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on **Start**
2. Click **All Programs**
3. Click on **Accessories**
4. Right click on **Command Prompt** icon
5. Click **Properties**
6. Click on the **Shortcut** tab on the top
7. Click the **Advanced** button at the bottom
8. Click on the check box that says:

   > Run as Administrator
9. Click **OK**
10. Go to the folder having the batch file
11. Enter the command which was giving

    > Access denied

    error

It will execute successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is supported by the wrapper. 
Maybe the way to go for you is to use the war within a servlet container.
Have a look here: http://archiva.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/adminguide/webapp.html

HTH

Answer (score 0):

pleas open Command Prompt run as administrator mode and then go to

**{tinydms-home}/bin**

then

**tinydms install**

to installing

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, reopening the console or restarting the computer solves this problem for me. I hope it works